# Linq Query: Convert Key value pair to generic list of objects

Tags: linq, dynamic

I have following list of  objects, it is like property & its value. I need to convert it  to generic list of objects.

```
public class Prop
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
} 

var list = new List<Prop>  {
    new Prop { Name = "x", Value = "10" },
    new Prop { Name = "y", Value = "11" },
    new Prop { Name = "z", Value = "12" },
    new Prop { Name = "x", Value = "101" },
    new Prop { Name = "y", Value = "102" },
    new Prop { Name = "z", Value = "103" }

};
```

Actually, I want to convert it to as shown below

```
var list2 = new List<xyx> {
    new  xyx { x = "10", y = "11", z = "12" },
    new  xyx { x = "101", y = "102", z = "103" }
};

public class xyx
{
    public string y { get; set; }
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string z { get; set; }
    public string d { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The second item of expected list seems invalid, the second x is 101 in the list, and y, z and d seems invalid too.

Comment: How do we determine which properties go into which `xyx` objects?

Comment: Thank for the reply... it depending on the Name. ie if name is x, then we need to assgine it to propery x in class xyx

Comment: Please let me know if you need more detail

Comment: will they always be ordered by default as x, y, z in the name / value pair list?  it seems to me whatever you are doing to create the generic list is flawed and you should be able to select into the xyz list directly before creating that object..?

Comment: You don't understand James's question. How do you know which triple of xyz belongs to one object? The rows seem to be ordered neatly, but what if they aren't? You should be able to group them by some identifier.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution done in LINQ.  I do not make any claim that it's the most efficient, and I'm not sure LINQ is the best way to do this, but it does get the job done.

I am assuming that the original list comes in groups of 3 (x,y,z), though the order of the grouping does not matter.

```
var list2 = list
    .Select((prop, index) => new { prop, index })
    .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, g => g.prop) //make groups of 3
    .Select(g => new xyx { 
         x = g.First(prop => prop.Name == "x").Value,
         y = g.First(prop => prop.Name == "y").Value,
         z = g.First(prop => prop.Name == "z").Value
    })
    .ToList();
```